An Unexpected error occured while Opening docker desktop on windows 10
Docker Desktop was unable to gather information about the current error. This most likely means that the services supporting Docker Desktop have exited unexpectedly.
If the issue persists, collect diagnostics and submit an issue⁠.
connect ENOENT \.\pipe\errorReporter
installed wsl2 on windows 10. after that downloaded docker desktop & installed successfully for WSL2.
while opening this application getting above error.

add yourself to docker users group
net localgroup docker-users username /add

